# CFBridgingRelease returns null when decoding a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, decode

I have this strange issue, this extension method returns null and I just don't get it.

```
- (NSString*) uriDecoded
    {
    return (NSString*) CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)self, CFSTR(""), kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is decode an encoded JSON string.

Thing is it doesn't always behave like this. To tell the truth sometimes it might not be a valid JSON string but should this matter in any way?

Regards.

Comment: CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding() is returning nil, and CFBridgingRelease() just passes it along.

Comment: May I know when this will happen? I try to debug and find out why this  is happening after I just tried to concatenate some strings and decode them.

Comment: Unchain your CF functions and check the results of each before returning so you can see what is happening. Your method should have some guards inside.

Comment: Functions that read string encodings typically return nil when the given data is not in fact valid in that encoding.